# Connect Azure webapp to sqlserver in rackspace

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have hosted a webapp in azure cloud.
My MS sql database is in rackspace which only allows a selected ip to access.
I can add more IPs to allow access to the rackspace database.
Which IP address of the Azure webapp should I add in rackspace?
Is it the customDomain's IP address or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't just one - check out [this doc](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653) - basically Azure Web Apps run in a server farm that's managed by Microsoft.  Unless you use an ASE (app service environment) you can't change this.  There are a couple of ways you can do what you're trying to do - either

1 - connect over the internet by opening up the ports on your rackspace VM - this will work, but opens you up to the possibility of a network layer attack from any app that someone hosts in Azure.  (so you're relying on authentication rather than network level protection).

2 - use a hybrid connection - this is an app service feature that allows you to download a gateway exe app that runs in your VM in rackspace, and then connects to the app service and creates a secure tunnel to it.  Hence, its outbound from your rackspace DC, you don't need to change firewall settings.  You can read about it and download the app from the azure portal (in app services).  You then configure the connection in your azure web app just as if the rackspace VM was on the same network.  (eg. you can use "localhost" if the gateway exe is running on the sql server).  This is the approach I'd recommend if you can't move your SQL estate to Azure SQL and hence locate it alongside your web apps.

Comment: When you say opening the ports in rackspace VM in your 1st option, which ports you mean?

Comment: 1433 is the usual one for sql on tcp